# UISearchBar clipped under status bar when added to UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want my search bar to draw its background extended upwards below the status bar like this:

[image]

This is the corresponding code for the image above:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    
    self.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"v":self.searchBar,
                            @"topLayoutGuide":self.topLayoutGuide};
    
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topLayoutGuide][v]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    
    [self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbarBG"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

**The problem arises when I add the search bar to a `UISearchDisplayController`** by appending the following line at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

Note that the image looks clipped. This is different from what it looks like if I change UIBarPositionTopAttached to UIBarPositionTop in the code:

[image]

The image being clipped made me think of `clipsToBounds` and I could get the search bar to display properly by adding this piece of code at the end of `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    subview.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

So I guess the `UISearchDisplayController` is messing with the `clipsToBounds` property of the `UISearchBar` background view. Has anyone else struggled with this? Is there a problem with my code?

### Update:

Back in October 2013, besides posting this question, I also reported this using the Apple Bug Reporter tool. On January 6, 2015 (waaaay too late) I got a reply from Apple Developer Relations:

> There are no plans to address this based on the following:
>
> UISearchDisplayController is no longer supported. The desired
> functionality should be available with UISearchController and if not
> (or is behaving incorrectly), please file a new bug.
>
> We are now closing this report.
>
> If you have questions about the resolution, or if this is still a
> critical issue for you, then please update your bug report with that
> information.
>
> Please be sure to regularly check new Apple releases for any updates
> that might affect this issue.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! In my case, a UITableViewController was involved and adding `self.tableView.clipToBounds = NO` solved it (although I'm not sure it's a good thing to do perf-wise so I'm only doing it when the search bar is activated)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same issue, but forcing clipsToBounds to YES for the searchBar, did the trick. No need of auto-layout nor UIBarPositioning protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

You conform to the `UIBarPositioningDelegate` protocol and upon properly becoming the delegate for your SearchBar, implement the delegate method as such

> `-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
>       return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
>   }`

Comment: My mistake. I have used it for bars placed in the storyboard with 20pt offset in iOS 7. I assumed it would work for your bar too. btw is the delegate being called for your search bar?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem only arises when I add the search bar to a `UISearchDisplayController`.